# How to create a class in python using Pyserial and how to initialize it

Tags: python, serial-port, python-3.6, pyserial, com-port

I want to create a class for a Temperature Chamber VTM7004 that has a 9PIN RS232.
The chamber has a male pinout with only GND, TXD, and RXD accessible.

I got a cable from amazon and I did a 1:1 connection between all the 3 PINS:
https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/product/B0758B874Y/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Here is my code:

```py
import serial
import time
import string

class VTM():

    def __init__(self):
        if (self.ChamberVTM7004.isOpen() != True):
            self.ChamberVTM7004 = serial.Serial(port='COM5',
                                                baudrate=9600,
                                                bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                                                stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                                                parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                                                timeout=5,
                                                xonxoff=False,
                                                rtscts=False,
                                                dsrdtr=False)

        else:
            print(self.ChamberVTM7004.portstr + " is open ")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Test = VTM()
```

This is the error I get:

```py
C:\Users\zbgmqg\Desktop\OnSemi20191125\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/zbgmqg/Desktop/OnSemi20191125/Automation/TemperatureChamber.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/zbgmqg/Desktop/OnSemi20191125/Automation/TemperatureChamber.py", line 106, in <module>
    Test = VTM()
  File "C:/Users/zbgmqg/Desktop/OnSemi20191125/Automation/TemperatureChamber.py", line 17, in __init__
    if (self.ChamberVTM7004.isOpen() != True):
AttributeError: 'VTM' object has no attribute 'ChamberVTM7004'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any help is highly appreciated :)

[Screenshot of my Project Interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQlFF.png)

Comment: Just remove the `if/else`. You only need `self.ChamberVTM7004 = serial.Serial(...`

Comment: You are testing ```self.ChamberVTM7004.isOpen()``` before you have assigned ```self.ChamberVTM7004```.

Comment: def __init__(self):

        
        self.ChamberVTM7004 = serial.Serial(port='COM5', baudrate=9600,
                                            bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                                            parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, timeout=5,
                                            xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)

Like this you mean?

Comment: Yes, just like that.

Comment: File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 64, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM5': FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.', None, 2)

Comment: What makes you think that the USB device shows up as `COM5`?

Comment: I use NI Max to check which COM port is connected.
I think the issue is mainly as there is no device connected to my laptop now.

I will check again and update you!

Thanks a lot man for the help ... much appreciated !

Comment: You may need to use [this](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html#module-serial.tools.list_ports) to get a list of the available ports.